# I'm trying to do a loop for this and this is what I did, but it will not work

Tags: vb.net, loops

I want to make all the labels, checkboxes and comboboxes to `Enabled` when the combobox item is 0.

```
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim MycbmQty As ComboBox = CType(Me.Controls("cbmQty" & i), ComboBox)
        Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblSumname" & i), Label)
        Dim MybtnSum As Button = CType(Me.Controls("btnSum" & i), Button)
        Dim myLabel2 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblSumPrice" & i), Label)
        Dim myLabel3 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblPriceTit" & i), Label)
        Dim myLabel4 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblQtyTit" & i), Label)
        Dim mychkname As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls("chkName" & i), CheckBox)

        If MycbmQty.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            myLabel.Enabled = False
            MybtnSum.Enabled = False
            myLabel2.Enabled = False
            myLabel3.Enabled = False
            myLabel4.Enabled = False
            mychkname.Checked = False
            MycbmQty.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

However, it will work if I do this instead.

```
 Private Sub cbmQty1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbmQty1.SelectedIndexChanged
    
    If cbmQty1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lblSumName1.Enabled = False
        btnSum1.Enabled = False
        lblSumPrice1.Enabled = False
        lblPriceTit1.Enabled = False
        lblQtyTit1.Enabled = False
        cbmQty1.Enabled = False
        chkName1.Checked = False
    End If

   
End Sub



Private Sub cbmQty2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbmQty2.SelectedIndexChanged
  
    If cbmQty2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lblSumName2.Enabled = False
        btnSum2.Enabled = False
        lblSumPrice2.Enabled = False
        lblPriceTit2.Enabled = False
        lblQtyTit2.Enabled = False
        cbmQty2.Enabled = False
        chkName2.Checked = False
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub cbmQty3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbmQty3.SelectedIndexChanged
   
    If cbmQty3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lblSumName3.Enabled = False
        btnSum3.Enabled = False
        lblSumPrice3.Enabled = False
        lblPriceTit3.Enabled = False
        lblQtyTit3.Enabled = False
        cbmQty3.Enabled = False
        chkName3.Checked = False
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub cbmQty4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbmQty4.SelectedIndexChanged
    
    If cbmQty4.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lblSumName4.Enabled = False
        btnSum4.Enabled = False
        lblSumPrice4.Enabled = False
        lblPriceTit4.Enabled = False
        lblQtyTit4.Enabled = False
        cbmQty4.Enabled = False
        chkName4.Checked = False
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub cbmQty5_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbmQty5.SelectedIndexChanged
   
    If cbmQty5.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lblSumName5.Enabled = False
        btnSum5.Enabled = False
        lblSumPrice5.Enabled = False
        lblPriceTit5.Enabled = False
        lblQtyTit5.Enabled = False
        cbmQty5.Enabled = False
        chkName5.Checked = False
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say, "it will not work".  Exactly what does that mean?  Have you done any sort of debugging?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What do you see when you step through the code? What does 'it will not work' mean? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not catch the Change event but query the actual state in the loop.

The goal is the `AddHandler` line.

```
Sub main


   For i = 1 To 5
        Dim MycbmQty As ComboBox = CType(Me.Controls("cbmQty" & i), ComboBox)
        Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblSumname" & i), Label)
        Dim MybtnSum As Button = CType(Me.Controls("btnSum" & i), Button)
        Dim myLabel2 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblSumPrice" & i), Label)
        Dim myLabel3 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblPriceTit" & i), Label)
        Dim myLabel4 As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lblQtyTit" & i), Label)
        Dim mychkname As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls("chkName" & i), CheckBox)


         AddHandler MycbmQty.SelectedIndexChanged, 
                   Sub()
                      If MycbmQty.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        lblSumName2.Enabled = False
                        btnSum2.Enabled = False
                        lblSumPrice2.Enabled = False
                        lblPriceTit2.Enabled = False
                        lblQtyTit2.Enabled = False
                        cbmQty2.Enabled = False
                        chkName2.Checked = False
                      End If
                   End Sub                                                       
    Next
end sub
```